# Firebase auth.js maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a small reactjs app that calls `firebase.createUserWithEmailAndPassword`. The call works without issue and my new user account is created. But then the app immediately dies with an exception coming from the firebase file auth.js, as shown above. Strange thing is both the then and catch both run.

```
static register(userId, password, fullName){
    return fbAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(userId, password);
}

static register(userId, password, userName){
return (dispatch) => {
  return AuthApi
    .register(userId, password, userName)
    .then((response, reject) => {
      debugger;
      const thisUserRef = fbDbUser.push({
        fullName: userName,
        userId: userId
      });

      dispatch({type: AuthActions.GOT_USER_SUCCESS, payload: thisUserRef});
    })
    .catch(error => {
      debugger;
      let registerErrorCode = error.code;
      let registerErrorMsg = error.message;

      toastr.error(registerErrorMsg);
      dispatch({type: AuthActions.GOT_USER_FAIL, payload: null});
    });
  };
}
```

Comment: The issue seems to be coming from the call to fbDbUser.push. When I remove this call the error does not happen.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this ?